# how to obfuscate using proGuard

Tags: java, proguard

I created a class FMSHandler and i exported it as a runnable jar named FMSCtrl_02.jar and the project has no main method, and there is a method inside the FMSHandler class called process(String fms).
In the lib directory of the proGuard I created a myconfig.pro file containing the following:

```
-injars       FMSCtrl_02.jar
-outjars      FMSCtrl_02_out.jar
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-printmapping FMSCtrl_02.map

-keep public class com.example.FMSHandler {

}
```

now when I imported the FMSCtrl_02_out.jar in another project, I found that method process(String fms) is not accessible!

How to obfuscate the code correctly?

Comment: obfuscate the code correctly = you want to keep the `process(String)` method? Otherwise you'd obfuscate the project only after it is fully assembled from non-obfuscated libraries

Comment: obfuscating code whilst keeping signatures isnt **that** useful ... you really should consider reducing your (publicly visible) classes down to a single one - centralize your "public interface" and run proguard **after** you changed everything else to *package/private/protected*, so to speak ... thats how you obfuscate.

Comment: @specializt it is only one public class. process(..) is a method!

Comment: un-hunh .... thats nice, i guess ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also specify the method you want to keep (with the correct signature).

```
-keep public class com.example.FMSHandler {
    public void process(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: Apparently reviewers reject this change again and again, but ProGuard requires the use of fully-qualified types, thus the correct signature of the method must be: public void process(java.lang.String)